# Error generating a signed APK in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, apk

I'm trying to generate a signed APK for android on react native, but I'm not getting it, the terminal is returning this error below:

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere


info Writing bundle output to:, C:\Users\paulo\Documents\Sperio\speriomob\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle
info Writing sourcemap output to:, C:\Users\paulo\Documents\Sperio\speriomob\android\app\build\generated\sourcemaps\react\release\index.android.bundle.map
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 10 asset files
info Done copying assets

> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\paulo\Documents\Sperio\speriomob\android\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:lintVitalRelease
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: C:\Users\paulo\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7b924f61dca3b36e28aeb94601753e06\android.jar with input C:\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar

> Task :app:validateSigningRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5m 46s
249 actionable tasks: 249 executed
```

Has anyone experienced this error and can help me, I'm desperate):

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't signed your app. Follow generating an upload key in this link:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

Otherwise, check if you have placed your keystore in /android/app/ folder

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I generated the keystore again, and the same error is still returning me):